# variable does not exist mapaccmap?

Tags: apex, trigger, variable

```java
public class UpdateHandler1 {
    public static void updateaccHandler(list<account> upac ){
        Map<Id, Account> mapaccmap = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Account acc : upac){
            if(acc.phone != mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).Phone){
                acc.description = 'Phone is updated, old phone mumber is ' + acc.mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).phone + ' & new phone is: '+ acc.phone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that in the actual code `mapaccmap` is always empty, so `mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).Phone` will throw a Null Pointer Exception. You should use that map only after putting some records into it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access variable `mapaccmap` from Account which is not exist. `acc` variable is type of `Account` and Account do not contains any property like `mapaccmap`.

Use `mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).phone` instead of `acc.mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).phone`

Corrected Code:

```
public class UpdateHandler1 {
    public static void updateaccHandler(list<account> upac ){
           Map<ID, account> mapaccmap = new Map<ID, account>();
         for(account acc : upac){
             if(acc.phone != mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).Phone){
                 acc.description = 'Phone is updated  , old phone mumber is'+ mapaccmap.get(acc.ID).phone +' & new phone is :'+ acc.phone;
             }
         }
    }
}
```